# How & What does the delete method for a file actually delete?

Tags: java, file, serialization, io, directory

Suppose I create a txt file and save it as **"Untitled1"**. I enter eclipse and type the following:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){
File f = new File("Untitled1.txt");
boolean isDeleted = f.delete();

System.out.println(isDeleted);

       }
}
```

False was returned from the delete method indicating the file was not deleted. I understand that a file object represents the location of a file and NOT the contents of the file. But then what is actually being deleted? How do you delete a location of a file, without deleting the contents of a file itself?

I also entered the file Path for the **Untitled1** file as a parameter to the File objects constructor, that did not delete the Untitled1.txt file either.

Comment: try giving the full path, then it would delete e.g. new File("C:\\Untitled1.txt");

Comment: It doesnt matter you still need to provide the absolute path otherwise f will be empty and delete would no nothing. since it is doing nothing there wont be any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is identified by its path through the file system, beginning from the root node.

Representation of the path depends on the system. e.g. in windows `C:\foo\bar` while in linux `/home/foo/bar`.

So in below code, string path would be converted into abstract pathname and it would create the `File` instance and when you call the `delete` method it will try to delete the node. Basically content and path are not really different.

```
File f = new File("Untitled1.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the file itself is deleted. False could be returned for a variety of reasons.

> `public boolean delete()`
>
> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.
>   Note that the `Files` class defines the `delete` method to throw an `IOException` when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted.
>
> Returns:
>   `true` if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; `false` otherwise
>
> Throws:
>
> `SecurityException` - If a security manager exists and its `SecurityManager.checkDelete(java.lang.String)` method denies delete access to the file

Catch the `SecurityException` and you will probably find that you are disallowed from directly deleting the file programmatically.

Comment: When I compile the code there is no Exception thrown. I created a try block before the file object was instantiated and closed the block after the print statement. I then placed a catch block catching exceptions of generic type Exception, with a printStackTrace method inside. However no exceptions are caught.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: You got it. Will remove

Comment: EJP recommended that you replace it with text, not delete it entirely. I added it back in text form. Trim it down or remove it again if you want to. I think it's useful information.

Answer (score -2):

First, please note that `File` is an old, [bad](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks) class, that should not be used nowadays.

It's a lot better to use the `Files` class, more specifically its [`delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method.

As for what exactly is deleted: a file is a bunch of bytes that sits in a hard disk. The disk - or one of its partitions - is formatted into a *filesystem*, which is a data structure that organizes directories and files. The particular filesystem dictates how the file is broken up into pieces, how these pieces can be located or added by operations such as *seek*, *read*, *write* etc.

A filesystem has directories, which give you start points for the files. The file path in the hierarchy of directories tells the system where to find the file, including all its information (like pointer to its start, read/write permissions, etc.) The information in the directory that tells where the actual file contents is is sometimes called a "link" (at least in Unix file systems).

When you delete a file, the usual thing that happens is that the particular link to that file from that directory is removed. If that is the last link (the file can be linked from more than one directory, at least in some file systems), the blocks that belong to the file are also marked as free so that they can be allocated to another file.

So your `File` object tells the system where the file is, but the `delete` operation ultimately tells the system both to unlink the file from the directory (the penultimate part of the path), and if that's the last link, it also tells the system to go to the file contents and mark it as free.

This is a general description. The exact details and what happens when the content is marked as free is dependent on the particular filesystem used (e.g. ext4,reiserFS... (Linux), HFS+ (MacOS X), NTFS,FAT32... (Windows)).